# How to handle throw er; unhandled 'err' event when setting up server using nodemon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, server, nodemon

So, basically I am setting up my local server using node.js and nodemon. It starts well on localhost but when I refresh the page or open another page,  the server crashes giving me this `unhandled 'error' event`. I have searched through some solutions and tried reinstalling the dependencies after removing the cache by using `npm cache clean --force`. There is an image attached showing the error.

[When I start my server using nodemon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4zGb.png)

[After refreshing the landing page or going to  other page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoY68.png)

**In case these images doesn't show up this is my whole return from vs code from starting the server to when I refresh the page or navigate to another page:**

```
> nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
server listening on port: 5000
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_http_outgoing.js:694:15)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:815:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SUJAL\OneDrive\Desktop\VS code\web development\NodeJs\nodejs\app.js:17:7)
    at Server.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:897:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17)
Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
    at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:753:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

If you can even help with a temporarily solution, it will be great.

Comment: It sounds like you have an hunandled exception in a promise. If you start your server without nodemon, did your server crash when your repeat your tests ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the port you're using is not in use by other services. Or, use a different port.

I had the same issue. Later realized port 5000 was being used by another service on my pc. Switched it to a different one and worked fine.